# using python, how do i loop using a for loop to display the records from each table showing all the columns and the respective column headers

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an sqlite database dummy data for call logs in android, using a query that selects the different tables from sqlite master,how do i loop using python for loop to display the records from each table showing all the columns and the respective column headers. Here is the piece in the python code:

```
for table in tables:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % table[0])
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print row # prints records in the all the tables without column headers
```

Comment: This code should work. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, sqlite doesn't support information_schema. you need to collect the tableschema separately.
we can use pragma,

```
cursor.execute('PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(tablename)
```

or we can use cursor.description,

```
column[0] for column in c.description
```

it will store the column names as a list.
you can modify your code, something like this.

```
for table in tables:
column = []
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % table[0])
rows = cursor.fetchall()
column = column[0] for column in cursor.description
i=0
for row in rows:
    if i == 0:
        print(column)
    else:
        print row # prints records in the all the tables without column headers
    i = i+1
```